# How do I permanently disable JavaScript strict warnings in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, javascript, firebug

When I open Firefox (8 Beta and 7) and load a page with firebug open, I get a load of JavaScript strict warnings, so I disable JavaScript strict warnings so my page loads will speed up, which works until I restart Firefox. Every time I open Firefox, JavaScript strict warnings are enabled. I even tried turning them off through the about:config settings.

How do I keep it off so I don't have to disable strict warnings every time I open Firefox?

Comment: about:config > javascript.options.strict.debug or javascript.options.strict ??

Comment: Tried those as well. strict.debug is set to false and strict will toggle to false, but when I restart the browser, it's always set to true.

Comment: Have you tried running in safe mode / in new profile? I guess this behavior might be related with some extension, perhaps JavaScript-related extensions. Look in their configuration thoroughly.

Comment: I disabled all the extensions I had installed, then started enabling them in sets and narrowed it down till I found every time I had PDF Download disabled, Javascript strict errors were disabled. Every time PDF Download was enabled, Javascript strict errors were enabled. So I'm keeping that extension disabled.
Thanks for the suggestion! I certainly wouldn't have pegged PDF Download to be the one. I figured maybe any number of CSS or Javascript editors/debuggers I had.

Answer (score 2):

In `about:config`, set this option to false:

```
extensions.firebug.showJSWarnings
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to `about:config`, and set `javascript.options.strict` to `false`.

If you run Firefox using the `cfx` tool (of the Addon SDK), then this will not help because the Addon SDK forces this preference to be `true` on start-up. To fix this, locate the directory containing the Addon SDK, open `python-lib/cuddlefish/prefs.py` and change

```
    'javascript.options.strict': True,
```

to

```
    'javascript.options.strict': False,
```

If you are bothered by deprecation warnings to the extent that they are not helpful (e.g. because you are a web developer that uses third-party libraries that are not going to be patched), then disable the warnings by setting
`devtools.errorconsole.deprecation_warnings` to `false` at `about:config`.

Comment: `devtools.errorconsole.deprecation_warnings` doesn't remove all the warnings. In particular, it doesn't remove [the one caused by AdBlock](https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/47).